# How do I get two values from one button in html?

Tags: php, html

this line is what Im using to send the values:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger"href="remove_profesor.php? prof_id=<php echo $row['prof_id'];?> course_section=<php echo $row['course_section'] ;?>
```

Im trying to have  button remove the assigned professor to the class. On the "view_courses.php" page theres a table with all the courses and theres a button next to each course that allows you to remove the professor that is assigned to that course. The button references "remove_professor.php". The issue im having is that "remove_professor.php" isnt recieving the second value which is "course_section".

This line is what im using to receive the values:

```
 $prof_id = $_GET['prof_id'];
 $course_section = $_GET['course_section'];
```

When I check the browser the values seems to be sending but then it gives me an error on the $course_section line, it says Undefined array key "course_section"

Comment: You need a & in between each key val. ?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3

Answer (score 1):

```
I think this code will help you
<?php 
    $prof_id = $row['prof_id'];                // this value is coming from database as passing to variable 
    $course_section= $row['course_section'];   // this value is coming from database as passing to variable 
?>
       
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="remove_profesor.php?prof_id=<?php echo $prof_id?> &course_section=<?php echo $course_section?>">Click Here </a>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the "&"

Comment: its ok brother, nice to help you

Answer (score 1):

There is MULTIPLE issues with your `a` tag ..  This is the *correction(s)* --  I'll explain below..

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="remove_profesor.php?prof_id=<?php echo $row['prof_id'];?>&course_section=<?php echo $row['course_section'] ;?>">LINK</a>
```

1. your `php` tags were invalid -- They need to be `<?php` not `<php` ..
2. Your `<a>` tag was incomplete .. No end quote and no end carat ..
3. You need to something to LINK .. And have and end tag `</a>`
4. You had a space in the URL parameters .. No spaces ..
5. Separate parameters with an ampersand `&`

Comment: for some reason i wrote <?php and this website wouldnt show the whole line so I removed the "?" so people could see the whole thing, but thanks!!!

Comment: Next time indent your code with (4) spaces in front of it .. Or surround it by *ticks* `\``  -- This will **format** it so it will be readable on the SO forum.

Answer (score 0):

To send multiple parameters with a GET, you have to separate them with `&`, like this:

```php
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="remove_profesor.php?prof_id=<?php echo $row['prof_id'];?>&course_section=<?php echo $row['course_section'];?">(link)</a>
```

It also seems that you write `<php` instead of the correct `<?php`.

Comment: I know that but for some reason if i put <?php it deletes the comment on this website

Comment: @ManuelRuiz I guess it interprets it as start of a PHP script and sanitizes it.